# Calculation of $\langle p\rangle$ and $\langle p^2\rangle$ for wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

> Given the wave function $$\psi(x)=A\exp\left[-a
> \left(\frac{mx^{2}}{\hbar}+it\right)\right]$$ I would like to calculate $\sigma_{p}$.

\begin{align}\langle p\rangle &=\int \psi^{\star}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\psi dx\\
&=2imaA^{2}\int xe^{-kx^{2}}dx\\
&=0
\end{align}
since the integrand is odd. (I let $k=\frac{2am}{\hbar}$)

Similarly,
\begin{align}
\langle p^2\rangle &=\int \psi^{\star}\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)^{2}\psi dx\\
&=-2A^{2}ma\hbar \left[\int kx^{2}e^{-kx^{2}}dx-\int e^{-kx^{2}}dx\right]\\
&=-2A^{2}ma\hbar\left[\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k}}-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k}}\right]\\
&=0 \end{align}

But doesn't this imply $\sigma_{p}=\sqrt{\langle \widehat p^{2}\rangle -\langle \widehat p\rangle ^{2}}=0$ ?

I think that I must have made a mathematical error, because this result as it stands would violate the uncertainty principle as I understand it: $\sigma_{x}\sigma_{p}\geq\frac{\hbar}{2}$

But I don't see anything incorrect. Does $\sigma_{p}=0$ violate the uncertainty principle?

Comment: The integrals you have look fine, but you've evaluated one of them with a factor out.

Comment: You also need to find the normalization constant, $A$, in order to get the value of $\sigma_p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in my calculation.

In fact: $\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-kx^{2}}dx = \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{k}}$

So $$\langle \widehat p^{2} \rangle=-2A^{2}ma\hbar [\frac{-1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{k}}]=ma\hbar$$ given that $A^{2}=\sqrt{\frac{2am}{\pi\hbar}}$ as calculated using the normalization condition.

This, can be used to calculate $$\sigma_{p}=\sqrt{ma\hbar}$$ It can similarly be shown that $$\langle x^{2}\rangle=\frac{\hbar}{4ma}$$ and $$\langle x \rangle= 0$$so $$\sigma_{x}=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{4ma}}$$ and finally: $$\sigma_{p}\sigma_{x}=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar^{2}ma}{4ma}}=\frac{\hbar}{2}\geq\frac{\hbar}{2}$$which agrees with the uncertainty principle.

Answer (score 3):

You have made an error in your calculation of ⟨p2⟩. You've evaluated two integrals, the second of which is off by a factor of two.

Comment: Ah: $\int ^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-kx^{2}}dx = \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{k}}$